# how to parse markdown via C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, html-parsing, markdown

I want to parse a markdown document and render it as formatted html, how can I do it please? Should I do this from scratch, or any API can be founded? so thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

and this blog posts may be useful: [Introducing MarkdownSharp](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/introducing-markdownsharp/) , [Markdown, One Year Later](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/markdown-one-year-later/) , and [Announcing Markdown.NET](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/markdown_announced). regards

Comment: You can use [MarkedNet](https://github.com/T-Alex/MarkedNet) project which support also GFM

Comment: @AlexTitarenko thanks. seems nice. i'll check it

Comment: You can have a look at [Markdig](https://github.com/lunet-io/markdig) the latest and most powerful Markdown in town for .NET! ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is a google code project [Markdownsharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/).

Description from the project:

> Open source C# implementation of Markdown processor, as featured on Stack Overflow.
>   This port is based heavily on the original Perl 1.0.1 and Perl 1.0.2b8 implementations of Markdown, with bits and pieces of the apparently much better maintained PHP Markdown folded into it. There are a few Stack Overflow specific modifications (which are all configurable, and all off by default). I'd like to ensure that this version stays within shouting distance of the Markdown "specification", such as it is...